# A different number of AFTER INSERT trigger alarms in SQLite and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, trigger, insert, sqlite

I have trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Foo]
AFTER INSERT
ON [Bar]
BEGIN  
  UPDATE Log SET count = count + 1;
END
```

When i execute query

```
insert into Bar (ColumnName) 
values ('SomeValue1'), ('SomeValue2'), ('SomeValue3'), ('SomeValue4')
```

trigger alarms 4 times in SQLite and 1 time in SQL Server. What's the reason?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, triggers can be fired "per row" or "per statement".

SQLite only supports ["per row" triggers](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) (hence why your trigger fires once for each row in your `INSERT` statement), while SQL Server only supports ["per statement" triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) (hence why your statement causes a single firing).

Other engines (e.g. [DB2](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-105) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html)) support both sorts of trigger which are specified by the phrases `FOR EACH ROW` or `FOR EACH STATEMENT` in the trigger's definition (though amusingly both have different defaults: DB2 defaults to per-row, PostgreSQL to per-statement). I vaguely recall Oracle supports both types too but there was something weird about its "per statement" variant.

Typically per-row triggers have access to the before/after state of the row they are triggered by, while per-statement triggers have access to a pseudo-table of the rows that the triggering statement affects.